# Understanding the relationship of displacement and electrical field of nonlinear material using fourier

Tags: fourier-transform, dielectric, non-linear-systems

**I posted this question first in math.stackexchange but was told it might be more suitable here.

I have a general formula of
$$D = P_0 + \epsilon_1 E + \epsilon_2 E^2 + \epsilon_3 E^3 + ...$$

with $D$ as the electrical displacement, $E$ the electrical field, $P_0$ for the polarization at zero-field and $\epsilon$ the permittivity for a nonlinear dielectric ->  [Source](https://electrons.wikidot.com/direction-electric-field-dependence-of-dielectric-constant)

With $E(t) = E cos(\omega t)$,

$$ D(t) = P_0 + \epsilon_1^*E_0 cos(wt) + \epsilon_2^*E_0^2 cos(2wt) + \epsilon_3^*E_0^3 cos(3wt)+ ...$$

and $D = \epsilon E$,

How do I go from:
$$ D(t) = D_0 + D_1cos(wt) + D_2cos(2wt) + D_3cos(3wt)+ ...$$
to
$$ D_0^* = P_0 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_2^*E_0^2 + \frac{3}{8}\epsilon_4^*E_0^4 + ... $$
$$ D_1^* = \epsilon_1^*E_0 + \frac{3}{4}\epsilon_3^*E_0^3 + \frac{10}{16}\epsilon_5^*E_0^5... $$
$$ D_2^* = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_2^*E_0^2 + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_4^*E_0^4 + \frac{15}{32}\epsilon_6^*E_0^6... $$
$$ D_3^* = \frac{1}{4}\epsilon_3^*E_0^3 + \frac{5}{16}\epsilon_5^*E_0^5 + \frac{21}{64}\epsilon_7^*E_0^7... $$

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Fourier Transformation/Series but I'm not sure how to derive them.

Comment: hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae

Comment: @hyportnex ah thanks! this answers my question!